# Object is undefined when trying to fetch it using useContext()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context, react-fullstack

I am very new to React and was trying to make a context in React so that in my notes app such that I can trigger my custom made alert for relevant user activity but when I am trying to use the values from the context using useContext I am getting error : "Cannot destructure property 'alert' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined."

Here's the code:-

**Creating Context**

```
import React from 'react';

const AlertContext = React.createContext(null);

export default AlertContext;
```

**Populating Value to the Context**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import AlertContext from "./AlertContext";

const ShowAlert = (props)=>{
    const [alert,setAlert] = useState(null);

    const showAlert = (message,type)=>{
            setAlert({
                msg:message,
                type:type
            })
            setTimeout(()=>{
                setAlert(null);
            },3000);
    }

    return(
        <AlertContext.Provider value={{alert,showAlert}}>
            {props.children}
        </AlertContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default ShowAlert;
```

**Trying to use the values**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Navbar, Button, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import ShowAlert from "../contexts/ShowAlert";
import MyAlert from "./MyAlert";

function Header() {

  const {alert} = useContext(ShowAlert);

  let history = useHistory();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    history.push("/login");
  };

  return (
    <>
    <header>
      <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" className="header">
        <Navbar.Brand className="heading">
          <Link to="/" className="headerLink">
            Note Cloud
          </Link>
          <i className="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt cloudIcon"></i>
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto"></Nav>
          {localStorage.getItem("token") && (
            <Nav>
              <Nav.Link>
                <Button variant="primary" size="lg" onClick={handleLogout}>
                  Logout
                </Button>
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          )}
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    </header>
   <MyAlert alert={alert}></MyAlert>
    </>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

**Edit:- MyAlert Component**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Alert } from "react-bootstrap";
import ShowAlert from "../contexts/ShowAlert";

const MyAlert = (props) => {
  
  const {alert} = useContext(ShowAlert);
  const capitalize = (word) => {
    if(word==="danger")
    {
      word = "error";
    }
    const lower = word.toLowerCase();
    return lower.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lower.slice(1);
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "50px" , width:"100%"}}>
      {alert && (
        <Alert
          variant={alert.type}
        >
          <Alert.Heading>{capitalize(alert.type)}</Alert.Heading>
          <p>{capitalize(alert.msg)}</p>
        </Alert>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyAlert;
```

**Error That I am getting**
[image]

[image]

Comment: alert is also a browser api function and this could also lead to some sort of problem. use another name, such as noteAlert.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the Context like this instead of null.

```
import React from "react";

const AlertContext = React.createContext({
  alert: {},
  setAlert: (alert) => {},
});

export default
```

Comment: thanks for the reply I tried it this way but same error persists, I have added the code of my MyAlert Component which is my final goal to implement if you could suggest any other way of doing that would also be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

i think your export is the fail

```
export const  AlertContext = React.createContext({})
```

or as well you can try:

```
< AlertContext.Consumer>
    {(context) => {
      console.log(context)
    }}
  </AlertContext.Consumer>
```

Comment: @m3w thanks for the reply I tried it this way(the first one by correcting my export) but same error persists.

Comment: @m3w I have added the code of my MyAlert Component which is my final goal to implement if you could suggest any other way of doing that would also be very helpful